# Get the value from JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to get the value from this currency conversion but am not quite sure how to go about it:

```
<script 
  type='text/javascript' 
  src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'> 
</script>
<script>
    $.get('http://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/convert?q=EUR_USD&compact=y', 
      function(theValue) {
        var conversion = (theValue);
        console.log(conversion);
      });
</script>
```

If you look in the console you can see:

```
{EUR_USD: {…}}EUR_USD: val: 1.178548
```

...and I need to display the val on the page, so that on the page I see 1.178548

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with 2 ways `theValue.EUR_USD.val` and `const {EUR_USD: {val: converEs6}} = theValue;`

```js
var theValue = {"EUR_USD":{"val":1.178693}}
var conversion = theValue.EUR_USD.val;
console.log(conversion);

const {EUR_USD: {val: convertEs6Style}} = theValue;
console.log(convertEs6Style)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :**

```js
 $.get('https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/convert?q=EUR_USD&compact=y', 
 function(theValue) {
   var conversion = theValue;
   console.log(conversion.EUR_USD.val);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `console.log(conversion.EUR_USD.val);`